# Moving a 3d block on a surface left and right by touch button or image instead of A - D Keys

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've made a little game with the help of YouTube tutorials and I have a problem.
Everything is OK with the game on pc, I use A, and D to move left or right a cube to avoid obstacles in front.
The Block has a forwardspeed to move by itself forward with a given speed.

But I want to test my game on my Android Phone so I have to control the object with touchscreen Buttons or touching the left or right part of the mobile screen.
With An or D keys it's easy, but with mobile touch... not so.
Down below is the code I use now for moving and a picture.

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {

    // This is a reference to the Rigidbody component called "rb"
    public Rigidbody rb;

    public float forwardForce = 2000f;  // Variable that determines the forward force
    public float sidewaysForce = 500f;  // Variable that determines the sideways force

    // We marked this as "Fixed"Update because we
    // are using it to mess with physics.
    void FixedUpdate ()
    {
        // Add a forward force
        rb.AddForce(0, 0, forwardForce * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Input.GetKey("d"))  // If the player is pressing the "d" key
        {
            // Add a force to the right
            rb.AddForce(sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("a"))  // If the player is pressing the "a" key
        {
            // Add a force to the left
            rb.AddForce(-sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }

        if (rb.position.y < -1f)
        {
            FindObjectOfType<GameManager>().EndGame();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not hard at all.
Start by extracting the movement into seperate methods

```
public void MoveRight()
{
   rb.AddForce(sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
}

public void MoveLeft()
{
   rb.AddForce(-sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
}

void FixedUpdate ()
{
    // Add a forward force
    rb.AddForce(0, 0, forwardForce * Time.deltaTime);
    if (Input.GetKey("d"))  // If the player is pressing the "d" key
            MoveRight();
    if (Input.GetKey("a"))  // If the player is pressing the "a" key
            MoveLeft();
}
```

All that's left to do is bind your buttons to those methods in the editor

Comment: It's perfect, a few tweeks and works perfect.

Thank you.